# $scope value not changing from the modalInstance.result.then() of the directive controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

HTML:

```
<teacher-modal modal-type="edit" file-name="teacherModal"
    button-title="DerecEdit" modal-value="teacher"
    button-class="" message="teacherCtrl.message">
</teacher-modal>|
 {{teacherCtrl.message}}
```

Directive:

```
(
function(){
    angular.module('MockApp')
        .directive('teacherModal',teacherModal);

    function teacherModal(){
        var directive = {
            restrict: 'EA',
            scope:{
                'type': '@modalType',
                'title': '@buttonTitle',
                'class': '@buttonClass',
                'fileName': '@fileName',
                modalValue: '=',
                message: '=',
            },
            template:'<a type="button" class="{{class}}" ng-click="modalDCtrl.open(modalValue,fileName)">{{title}}</a>',
            controller:'modalDirectiveController as modalDCtrl'
        }
        return directive;
    }

    angular.module('MockApp')
        .controller('modalDirectiveController', modalDirectiveController);

    modalDirectiveController.$inject = ['$uibModal','TeacherService','$scope', '$rootScope'];

    function modalDirectiveController($uibModal , TeacherService , $scope, $rootScope){

        var vm = this;

        vm.open = function(teacher,fileName){
            var msg;

            console.log('open function of teacher modal ctrl' + fileName);
            var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
                ariaLabelledBy: 'modal-title',
                ariaDescribedBy: 'modal-body',
                templateUrl: 'components/modalComponent/teacher/'+fileName+'.html',
                controller: 'TeacherModalController as teacherModalCtrl',
                size: 'md',
                resolve:{
                    newTeacher:function(){
                        return teacher;
                    }
                }
            });

            modalInstance.result.then(function (result) {
                console.log('result of directive controller');

                if(result.actionType == 'Add Teacher')
                    $scope.message = result.teacherName + " has been added";
                else
                    $scope.message = result.teacherName + " has been edited";
//<!-- The above $scope.message is not being viewed but I want to show this message -->
                $rootScope.$broadcast("updateMessage", msg);
            }, function () {
                console.info('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
            });
 // <!-- This $scope is being viewed but I dont want to show this message -->
            //$scope.message = 'hello from teacher-modalnn.js';
        }
    }

}
)();
```

**$scope.message** inside the modalInstance.result.then() function is not previewing whereas the **$scope.message** outside the function is being viewed.

When we use the $rootScope.broadcast() the message is being previewed, but I would not like to use the $broadcast service.

**Github** URL: https://github.com/coderabin01/ngStudentApp 
Can anyone answer me why and how?

Comment: The code instantiates the controller with "controllerAs" syntax and then the controller use $scope. Mixing 'controllerAs' with $scope is not wise. Use `bindToController: true`.

Comment: After using **service** to save and get the message, I was able to preview message.

Answer (score 0):

You are applying a value outside out of the angular context (XHR call), so you need to use $apply().

> $apply() is used to execute an expression in AngularJS from outside of
>   the AngularJS framework. (For example from browser DOM events,
>   setTimeout, XHR or third party libraries). Because we are calling into
>   the AngularJS framework we need to perform proper scope life cycle

So try this:

```
...
$scope.$apply(function() {
        $scope.message = result.teacherName + " has been added";
});
...
```

Comment: Thats not correct. `$uibModal` is an AngularJS module which is part of the digest cycle.